# Efficiency: multiple geom_line() or gather() - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyr

I have been doing plots for a while, and sometimes I ask myself what is the fastest (a.k.a. most efficient or best practices) way to do multiple lines in a plot with `dplyr` and `ggplot2`:

```
data <- airquality %>%
    group_by(Month) %>%
    summarise(mean_Ozone = mean(Ozone, na.rm=TRUE),
             mean_Solar.R = mean(Solar.R, na.rm=TRUE),
             mean_Wind = mean(Wind),
             mean_Temp = mean(Temp))
```

**Alternative 1:**

```
data %>%
ggplot(aes(x=Month)) +
geom_line(aes(y=mean_Ozone, color="blue")) +
geom_line(aes(y=mean_Solar.R, color="red")) +
geom_line(aes(y=mean_Wind, color="yellow")) +
geom_line(aes(y=mean_Temp, color="green"))
```

**Alternative 2:**

```
data %>%
gather("key", "value", -Month) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=Month, y=value, color=key)) +
geom_line()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Reshaping from wide to long is always better and more "manageable" but it might depend on the actual case.

Comment: Alternative 2 is the way to go

Comment: It depends on your data, the variables and how you want to group. If you want to plot one variable and also use it for grouping/ aesthetics, go for the long format. If, however, you want to plot two or more (different) variables and use different groupings, you may indeed fare better with alternative 1.